# Construct a Turing Machine to increment any binary number

Tags: turing-machines

Construct  a  Turing  Machine 
to  increment  any  binary  number
.

(for 
example,  if
the 
input
is
10010 then the output will be 10011 
and if the input 111 then the output will 
be 1000

Comment: Not really, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered it here:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/76316/72320

If you have any questions about it, I'll be glad to answer it.

Comment: I tried your answer , but when i give input 10010 on jflap program  then it says it rejected but i want it to increment by one  as 10011 

turing machine is a self study for as ,  so im really i dont know how i will check if it will increment by one or not . >.<!

Comment: @SAKOORASARANYAA as you can see in this [image](http://imgh.us/Screenshot_from_2017-06-05_23-52-53.png), It is accepted and the result is 10011. Tnx for introducing me to jflap :))

Comment: U too Thank u ,, i understand it now ^.^